# How many elements does the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt3]/(5)$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think that there are 5 elements($[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]$), but I am not sure, because I don't understand how to solve it.
I have such solution: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt3]/(5)\simeq\mathbb{F_5}[x]/(x^2-3)$, which means that this ring consists of such elements: $a_1\cdot x+a_0$ where $a_0$ and $a_1$ can be equal to {0,1,2,3,4}. So, there are $5^2=25$ elements. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Hint: how does an arbitrary element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$ look like? How does an arbitrary element of $(5)$ look like?

Comment: So, which of those five elements does $\sqrt3$ correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z[\sqrt3]/(5)\cong \Bbb Z[x]/(5,x^2-3)\cong \Bbb Z_5[x]/(x^2-3) $

Theorem: Let $F$ is a finite field of order $q$ and $f(x)$ be a polynomial in $F[x]$ of degree $n>0 $, then $F[x]/(f(x))$ has $q^n$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\mathbf Z[\sqrt 3]/(5)\simeq\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2-3)\bigm/5\cdot\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2-3)\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\bigm/(X^2-3)$$
is a $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$-vector space. What is its dimension?